# Парсинг строки из json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Добрых времени суток, вопрос заключается в следующем: с сервера приходит `json`, в нем находится объект `'content': '<p>Hello world</p>'`

При вставке в html документ {...content}, то будет выводить строку `<p>Hello world</p>`

Можно ли как-то убрать ковычки из документа? чтобы в html документ уже закинулся этот сам тег `<p></p>` с содержимым, то бишь просто слово Hello world в теге `<p></p>`

Comment: Добавьте код к вашему вопросу, каким образом добавляете в html значение content

Comment: {properties[0].article.content}

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerHTML = content` как то так вы должны с помощью js добавлять в html свои элементы

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, я использую React

Comment: Ну тогда вы описывайте что используете, и желательно прикладывайте Ваш код.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, вот как есть, так и описал, по-другому не могу, нужно лишь узнать как убрать строку и превратить её в теги, которые там будут, допустим я получу строку из json: <p>Hello</p><br/><p>world</p> и вместо того, чтобы он мне просто вывел эту строку, нужно, чтобы получились теги

Comment: В реакте надо шаманить https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, ваш вариант с innerHTML подошёл, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var json = '{"content":"<p>Hello World</p>"}';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
//убираем знаки тега
var str = data.content.replace(/<p>/, "").replace(/<\/p>/, "");
//далее используем переменную str по своему усмотрению
console.log(str);
```